Laravel DomPDF table border
I am using DOMPDF library for Laravel. I generate pdf using approach from documentation.
            $mainPdf = Pdf::loadView('banks_preferred.main', $necessaryData)
                ->setPaper('letter', 'portrait')
                ->setOption('isFontSubsettingEnabled', true)
                ->setOption('isRemoteEnabled', true)
                ->setOption('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true)
                ->setOption('margin-top', 50)
                ->setOption('margin-bottom', 50)
                ->setOption('margin-left', 30)
                ->setOption('margin-right', 30)
                ->setOption('font', 'fonts/lucida-console.ttf')
                ->setOption('isPhpEnabled', true)
                ->output();

I faced such problem. I have different colors of table border and its <td> elements. and I can't repeat bottom border of table at the end of page if my table goes to the next page. How can I do it? I tried to do positioning. But it didn't help.
enter image description here
I added absolute and fixed positioning, used pseudo-elements.
This is template of my layout:
<table class="tab" style="border: 1.5px solid;" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
        <tr style="height:10pt">
            <td style="width:572pt;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-width:1.5px;border-bottom-color:#005B43;border-top-style:solid;border-top-width:1.5px;border-top-color:#000;"
                colspan="3" bgcolor="#468876">
                <p class="s2"
                   style="padding-left: 12pt;text-indent: 0pt;line-height: 8pt;text-align: left;margin-top: 1px; margin-bottom: 2px;">
                    ******</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height:9pt; border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-width:1pt;border-bottom-color:#005B43">
            <td style="width:52pt;border-top-style:solid;border-top-width:0;border-top-color:#005B43; border-bottom: 1.5px solid #005b43;"
                bgcolor="#468876">
                <p class="s5" style="padding-right: 7pt;text-indent: 0pt;line-height: 8pt;text-align: center;">Date</p>
            </td>
            <td style="width:203pt;border-top-style:solid;border-top-width:0;border-top-color:#005B43;border-bottom: 1.5px solid #005b43;"
                bgcolor="#468876">
                <p class="s5" style="padding-left: 14pt;text-indent: 0pt;line-height: 8pt;text-align: left;">Description
                </p>
            </td>
            <td style="width:317pt;border-top-style:solid;border-top-width:0;border-top-color:#005B43;border-bottom: 1.5px solid #005b43;"
                bgcolor="#468876">
                <p class="s5" style="padding-right: 223pt;text-indent: 0pt;line-height: 8pt;text-align: right;">Amount
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="duocolor">
        @forelse($credit_array as $credit)
            <tr style="height:8pt;">
                <td style="width:52pt;">
                    <p class="s3"
                       style="padding-left: 5pt;padding-right: 7pt;text-indent: 0pt;text-align: center;">
                        {{ $credit['date'] }}</p>
                </td>
                <td style="width:203pt;">
                    <p class="s3"
                       style="padding-left: 14pt;text-indent: 0pt;text-align: left;">{!! $credit['description'] !!}</p>
                </td>
                <td style="width:317pt;">
                    <p class="s3" style="padding-right: 223pt;text-indent: 0pt;text-align: right;">{{(string)$credit['amount']}}
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @empty
            <tr style="height:8pt;">
                <td colspan="3" style="width:100%; border-bottom: 1.5px solid #000;">
                    <p class="s3" style="padding-left: 5pt;padding-right: 7pt;text-indent: 0pt;text-align: left;">
                        No Credits
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforelse
        </tbody>

    </table>


Try this, 
1.You can try setting the border on the tbody instead of the table. This way, the borders of the rows will inherit the styles correctly. Modify your tbody tag as follows:
<tbody class="duocolor" style="border: 1.5px solid #005B43;">
2.Add border-collapse: collapse; to combine borders properly. You can add this style to your  tag:
<table class="tab" style="border: 1.5px solid; border-collapse: collapse;" cellspacing="0">

Hi. Thanks for the answer. But I tried to do this. It does not help. The library itself divides the pages and the lower border is drawn only where the table ends.
